# Enabling TLS on production network with Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm curious to know the best method for generating the necessary TLS certificates needed for secure communication between network components when **not** using the `cryptogen` tool.

Registering/enrolling identities using Fabric CA will get you a keypair necessary for network transactions, but can these same keypairs be used for securing network communications, or should I be provisioning those separately using openssl?

Comment: Not sure there was a -1 here?  Seems like a decent question to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you **could** use the enrollment keypair for TLS communication, but that is **not recommended** since ideally you would not use the same keypair for multiple purposes.

There are a few options:

1) You can run a separate instance of fabric-ca and use it to issue TLS certificates

2) You can use the [multi-root capability](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#setting-up-multiple-cas) of fabric-ca and use one of the roots for signing keypair and the other for TLS keypair

3) Use a service like LetsEncrypt

4) Use a utility like openssl to do it

Comment: Isn't enrolling the tls cert the same? Why does it make sense to generate it with openssl for example?

Comment: The main point is that the enrollment certificate and the TLS certificate should not be issued by the same certificate authority.  Given the number of TLS certs will likely be low (compared to the number of enrollment certificates), openssl was just a suggestion.